# how can i extract a name of a span using java?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, html

i need to compile a pattern in order to have the name of the span but in vain i can't have what i want may be it's the way that this pattern is written i know that i made something not totaly correct .. this is my html code :

```
<span class="libelleAttributPageParametrage"> 
 "Libellé de facturation"
<font color="#C60307">*</font>
</span>
```

and this is my java code :

```
 public List<String> getAllSpan()
{
    String HTMLSource = priceSelenium.getHtmlSource();
    priceSelenium.getBodyText();
    List<String> ListOfSpan = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "<SPAN[^>]*>([\\w\\d\\s\\n\\r()/°@\\.\\-àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ]*)</SPAN>" );
    Matcher m = p.matcher( HTMLSource );
    while ( m.find() )
    {
        if ( !m.group( 1 ).isEmpty() )
        {
            ListOfSpan.add( m.group( 1 ) );
        }
    }
    return ListOfSpan;
}
```

and what i need to have in my ListOfSpan is :"Libellé de facturation"

thanks in advance

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒‌​͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an HTML parser instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse HTML, you should use an HTML parser library (such as [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)).  This will give you an object graph representing the HTML, with which you can navigate to the `<span>` object you're interested in and call something like `spanElem.attr("name")`.

HTML is not a regular language, and so treating it as text and trying to extract parts with regexes is not strictly possible.  It might work for a while in simple cases, but it's still likely to involve an overly complex regex, which will fail for some valid HTML.  [That way lies madness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/45664).